# How to debug this regular expression puzzle?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this test code:

```
  string triggerPoint = "<TP DDI=\"\" DQ=\"Y\" EDN=\"141040\" NE=\"141049\" NSU=\"141049\" OOH=\"141049\" QZ=\"1007\" QDN=\"141050\" QF=\"141049\" QT=\"M\" RC=\"141049\" RC2=\"\" TWE=\"141049\"/>";
        string pattern = "(?<=QZ=\").*?(?=\"\\s)";

        var match = Regex.Match(triggerPoint, pattern);

        string queueID = match.Groups[0].Value;

        Assert.AreEqual("1007", queueID);
```

Which works, but the following code doesn't:

```
string triggerPoint = "<TP DDI=\"\" DQ=\"Y\" EDN=\"141040\" NE=\"141049\" NSU=\"141049\" OOH=\"141049\" Q=\"1007\" QDN=\"141050\" QF=\"141049\" QT=\"M\" RC=\"141049\" RC2=\"\" TWE=\"141049\"/>";
        string pattern = "(?<=Q=\").*?(?=\"\\s)";

        var match = Regex.Match(triggerPoint, pattern);

        string queueID = match.Groups[0].Value;

        Assert.AreEqual("1007", queueID);
```

All I have done is to remove the Z from QZ in the triggerPoint string and the pattern. However, instead of now returning a queueID of 1007, it returns "Y".

The second snippet is what I actually need to work. Please can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: `DQ=\"Y\"` Does that give you a clue? Try `string pattern = "(?<=\\bQ=\").*?(?=\"\\s)";`

Comment: It is some sort of XML, why not use an XML parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex (your try)

```
(?<=Q=").*?(?="\s)
```

matches anything between `Q="` and `"` (double quote followed by a space). It doesn't care what precedes the `Q`.

If you add a *word boundary* before the `Q` it will make sure no character (nor digit) is present just before it, like in the case with `DQ="Y"`, which is what your regex finds. So

```
(?<=\bQ=").*?(?="\s)
```

should do it.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NKDJ1s/1). (regex101 doesn't *support* C# flavor, but it's more illustrative than alternatives (known to me) and the RE is the same).

Don't forget to escape the necessary characters.

Comment: Hi ClasG. Firstly, let me say I am in awe of anyone who can decipher regular expressions, so thank you very much for this explanation and you have my undying admiration!

Couldn't get it to work at first, but once I had escaped the \b i.e. (?<=\\bQ=\").*?(?=\"\\s), it worked a treat. I don't really understand why it needs escaping as it's not a literal, but it works so I'm happy :-)

Comment: Glad to help. Since the `\b` is a regex metacharacter, the ``\`` is interpreted by the regex parser. To have a literal ``\`` in a string in C#, it needs to be escaped. Otherwise C# sees it as an escape character and interprets the `\b` as *backspace*. You could of course use a verbatim-string-literal to avoid that: `string pattern = @"(?<=\bQ="").*?(?=""\s)"";`. Then, as you see, you'd have to have double double-quotes. (And... if this answer got it to work for you, please mark as accepted ;)